# WPF ListView Binding with UpdateSourceTrigger set to explicit strange behaviour

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, updatesourcetrigger

I have a `ListView` with different `DataTemplate`s set up to bind. I want to update some of the columns (mix of textblock and progress bar) when I call `UpdateSource()` on a bindingexpression. I also want to update 1 of the columns when the property is changed which it is bound too.

I was able to get the `PropertyChanged` behaviour to work. But whenever I change the property of one of the other columns they update straight await, instead of on the `UpdateSource` call. It would appear that its ignoring the `UpdateSourceTrigger` which is set in the xaml and is using the default behaviour.

I have a class which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

The xaml for the column I want to update explicitly looks like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Percentage" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Percentage, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

And the xaml for one which I want to update on property change:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

My binding is set originally like so:

```
Binding downloadBinding = new Binding();

downloadBinding.Source = _downloads;

ListDownloads.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, downloadBinding);
```

If I execute the following code:

```
_downloads[0].Percentage += 0.3;
_downloads[0].FileSize = 700.00;
_downloads[1].Percentage += 10;
```

The column percentage column is updated straight away, but I would expect it to wait for the call on UpdateSource().

My code for updating the source is:

```
BindingExpression be = ListDownloads.GetBindingExpression(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty);
be.UpdateSource();
```

Am I missing something? I can't find anything online or in a book about why this is happening.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the source and the target... the source is your _`downloads` collection, the target is the `GridViewColumn`. The `UpdateSourceTrigger` property controls when the **source** is updated by the control, but I assume your grid it not editable, so you don't need to use this property.

The update of the target is always immediate, there is no `UpdateTargetTrigger` property...

Comment: So, would the only way to refresh the listview would be to rebind or something along those lines?

Comment: The listview is refreshed when the data changes, because your objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged